# Text resource not loading

Tags: unity, software-engineering

I'm trying to load text from a .txt file into a `TextAsset` variable. The file is in the assets folder under `Texts/`. My problem is that `bindata` is returned as null.

```
string instructions; 

void Start ()
{
    //LOAD TEXT ASSETS

    TextAsset bindata = Resources.Load ("Texts/Instructions") as TextAsset;
    instructions = bindata.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load a resource through [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), the file itself must be located in a subfolder of `Asset/Resources`. Try to move it there and your command will work.